# Unable to generate native file using JNI from .java in Netbeans

Tags: java, c++, netbeans, java-native-interface

I'm encountering difficulties in generating a JNI file out based on the tutorial available from netbeans :
https://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/beginning-jni-win.html

My codes are similar as per the ones written in the website as well :
[image]

Im receiving the error as shown below :
[image]

Im sure it isnt a problem with my javah programme as i fixed it in my PATH variables. So what am I exactly doing wrong here? Appreciate if someone could point me the right direction

Comment: It's a problem with the arguments. You haven the .h file name followed by several options. Options come first. Check the syntax.

Comment: I have changed to javah -classpath JNIDemoJava2/build/classes helloworld.main -o JNIDemoJava.h  but the problem is still the same as shown in the screenshot. I dun tink is a syntax problem ...

Comment: You haven't fixed the problem yet, you've just changed it. I repeat. Options come first. Of course it's a syntax error.

Comment: yep figured out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
javah -o JNI.h -jni -classpath "C:\Users\jneo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld\build\classes" helloworld.Main
```